# Why do I get Unable to unmarshall exception response using the AWS SDK for Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have a Java 17 project, which interacts with DynamoDB Local and configures and deploys it while running tests.

Here is some of the code I have in my test:

```java
var mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put(":test", new AttributeValue().withS("tomato"));

var query = " ( contains(value, :test)) ";


mapper.batchSave(Arrays.asList(
        DynamoTestModel.builder().value("mango").build(),
        DynamoTestModel.builder().value("avocado").build(),
        DynamoTestModel.builder().value("other fruit").build(),
        DynamoTestModel.builder().value("other other fruit").build(),
        DynamoTestModel.builder().value("jack fruit").build(),
        DynamoTestModel.builder().value("tomato").build()
));

var scanResult = mapperscanPage(DynamoTestModel.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression()
        .withFilterExpression(query)
        .withExpressionAttributeValues(attributes));


Assertions.assertEquals(1, scanResult.getCount());
Assertions.assertEquals("tomato", scanResult.getResults().get(0).getValue());
```

The above produces this error:

> Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0AS59VHPQ7IO0OIEQI4J9PEQIRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0AS59VHPQ7IO0OIEQI4J9PEQIRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)

What's the issue?

Comment: You using an old Java API. You should strongly consider updating to AWS SDK for Java V2 and the Enhanced Client.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue with DynamoDB Local.

> Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided

The first part of your exception is just an issue with your setup, which I explain in detail [here](https://repost.aws/articles/ARPPEPfTPLTlGLHIsVVyyyYQ/troubleshooting-unable-to-unmarshall-exception-response-with-the-unmarshallers-provided-in-java).

> Error Code: ValidationException

This is the real issue. `ValidationException` is usually related to a syntax which is not correct.

```
var query = " ( contains(value, :test)) ";
```

What is `value` here? It should be an attribute name. value is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) in DynamoDB, if your attribute name is called `value` then you should use `ExpressionAttributeNames`.

And if you are not using a reserved keyword and `value` is not the name of your attribute, you can simply do it like this:

```
var query = "contains(myAttributeName, :test)";
```

And one final note is that you are being returned a RequestId in the stack trace which means you are not hitting DynamoDB Local but the web service.